# MongoDB $group + $sum aggregation is very slow

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have an aggregation query in MongoDB:

```
[{
    $group: {
        _id: '$status',
        status: {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
}]
```

It is running on a collection that has ~80 million documents. The status field is indexed, yet the query is very slow and runs for around 60 seconds or more.

I did an `explain()` on the query, but still got almost nowhere:

```
{
        "explainVersion" : "1",
        "stages" : [
                {
                        "$cursor" : {
                                "queryPlanner" : {
                                        "namespace" : "loa.document",
                                        "indexFilterSet" : false,
                                        "parsedQuery" : {

                                        },
                                        "queryHash" : "B9878693",
                                        "planCacheKey" : "8EAA28C6",
                                        "maxIndexedOrSolutionsReached" : false,
                                        "maxIndexedAndSolutionsReached" : false,
                                        "maxScansToExplodeReached" : false,
                                        "winningPlan" : {
                                                "stage" : "PROJECTION_SIMPLE",
                                                "transformBy" : {
                                                        "status" : 1,
                                                        "_id" : 0
                                                },
                                                "inputStage" : {
                                                        "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                                                        "direction" : "forward"
                                                }
                                        },
                                        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
                                }
                        }
                },
                {
                        "$group" : {
                                "_id" : "$status",
                                "status" : {
                                        "$sum" : {
                                                "$const" : 1
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
        ],
        "serverInfo" : {
                "host" : "rack-compute-2",
                "port" : 27017,
                "version" : "5.0.6",
                "gitVersion" : "212a8dbb47f07427dae194a9c75baec1d81d9259"
        },
        "serverParameters" : {
                "internalQueryFacetBufferSizeBytes" : 104857600,
                "internalQueryFacetMaxOutputDocSizeBytes" : 104857600,
                "internalLookupStageIntermediateDocumentMaxSizeBytes" : 104857600,
                "internalDocumentSourceGroupMaxMemoryBytes" : 104857600,
                "internalQueryMaxBlockingSortMemoryUsageBytes" : 104857600,
                "internalQueryProhibitBlockingMergeOnMongoS" : 0,
                "internalQueryMaxAddToSetBytes" : 104857600,
                "internalDocumentSourceSetWindowFieldsMaxMemoryBytes" : 104857600
        },
        "command" : {
                "aggregate" : "document",
                "pipeline" : [
                        {
                                "$group" : {
                                        "_id" : "$status",
                                        "status" : {
                                                "$sum" : 1
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                ],
                "explain" : true,
                "cursor" : {

                },
                "lsid" : {
                        "id" : UUID("a07e17fe-65ff-4d38-966f-7517b7a5d3f2")
                },
                "$db" : "loa"
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

I see that it does a full `COLLSCAN`, I just can't understand why.

I plan on supporting a couple hundred million (or even a billion) documents in that collection, but this problem hijacks my plans for seemingly no reason.

Comment: Everything seems "fine" to me. Did you try to rebuild the index by dropping it and create it again in background mode?

Comment: @ray Tried to do so but found no improvement, unfortunately. :/ I found a forum topic that mentions something similar on MongoDB but without solution: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/how-to-accelerate-an-aggregate-query-with-sum/109891

Answer (score 1):

You can advice the query planner to use the index as follow:

```
db.test.explain("executionStats").aggregate(
   [
     {$group:{ _id:"$status" ,status:{$sum:1} }}
   ],
     {hint:"status_1"}
   )
```

Make sure the index name in the hint is same as created ...
(db.test.getIndexes() will show you the exact index name )

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This, and doubling the memory in the server helped a little bit, but the issue is not solved. I increased the memory from 48GB to 96GB, used the hint and got back this as a result: https://pastebin.com/pkXYHKM1 The input stage took 3 seconds, projection 5 seconds while the whole operation 67 seconds. I was a bit puzzled, but later I realized that the processing (counting?) happens only on one CPU core. That core runs at 100% while everything else stands around 0%. Is there a way to make this aggregation parallel? There should be a divine & conquer algorithm for this?

Comment: Maybe sharding is an option , what is the size of database , size of cache and mongodb version ?

Comment: I have two collections the one I'm aggregating on has 78 million documents, 8GB storage size, and 9.2GB index size. The other one has 270M and 23.7 GB storage size and 18.4 GB index size. The version is 5.0.6 Community. The DB is running on a bare-metal server with 96GB ram and the CPU is a Ryzen 5 2600. Nothing else was running on the server at the time of the test and no other queries were done at that time.

Comment: Ohh, the cache size configured is ~50GB according to db.serverStatus().wiredTiger.cache. I missed this one sorry. Everything should fit in there nicely as far as I see. Sharding adds some complexity I would like to avoid. I'll probably just do a query and cache the value for 10-15 minutes then instead. I'm a bit sad that MongoDB doesn't support parallel aggregates tbh, but it fits my usecase very well for everything else.

Comment: I guess you follow all the mongodb production notes recommendation like THP disabled etc?

Comment: Yes, THP is disabled and swappiness is set to 1.